# How to set up a proxy location for all paths except some with apache2?

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, mod-proxy

I've got several webapps running on my webserver:

- SVN Repository Browser, accessible via `https://beta.mydomain.tld/svn/repos`
- Trac instance, accesible via `https://beta.mydomain.tld/trac`
- My own java web application, accessible via `http://beta.mydomain.tld/`, using a Proxy for the local Apache Tomcat on port 8080

Please note that the first two are available via SSL, the third is not (yet). Now I need to make my web app available via https, but I want Trac and SVN Browser still to be accessible in their current location.

I.e. I am trying to configure apache2 to proxy all requests not starting with `svn` or `trac` to Tomcat.

For the existing SSL web apps, there's the following configuration

```
    <Location /svn/repos>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /home/myuser/svn
        SVNListParentPath on
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion repository"
        AuthUserFile /home/myuser/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Location>

    <Location /trac>
        SetHandler mod_python
        PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
        PythonOption TracEnvParentDir /home/myuser/trac
        PythonOption TracUriRoot /trac
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Trac"
        AuthUserFile /home/myuser/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
```

I tried to add the following location, but it did not help anything...

```
    <Location />
        ProxyPass           http://localhost:8080
        ProxyPassReverse    http://localhost:8080/
    </Location>
```

For further information, here is the complete apache2 configuration regarding the SSL part (without any of my failed trials in it - I think it is default trac configuration):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName beta.mydomain.tld:443

    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
            Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/ssl.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl.key

    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    <Location /svn/repos>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /home/myuser/svn
        SVNListParentPath on
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Subversion repository"
        AuthUserFile /home/myuser/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Location>

    <Location /trac>
        SetHandler mod_python
        PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
        PythonOption TracEnvParentDir /home/myuser/trac
        PythonOption TracUriRoot /trac
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Trac"
        AuthUserFile /home/myuser/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just put ProxyPass ! into those two Location blocks. That stops proxying for the locations concerned.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same scenario (on windows). For anybody struggling with this:

It only started to work for me when I moved the "svn location" part *before* the Proxy* directives.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.domain.com
  DocumentRoot "C:/Apache/domain"
  ServerAdmin admin@domain.com

  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl/domain.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl/domain.key"
  SSLCertificateChainFile "conf/ssl/domain.ca-bundle.crt"

  <Location /svn>   
    DAV svn
    SVNPath "C:/svnrepo"
    SSLRequireSSL 
    AuthName "www.domain.com"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile "conf/svn/users"
    AuthGroupFile "conf/svn/groups"
    Require valid-user

    # needs to come before the ProxyPass directives
    ProxyPass !
  </Location>

  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPreserveHost on

  ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8080/    
</VirtualHost>
```